# Registration users in Hippo cms

Tags: authentication, registration, hippocms

I have another question about Hippo cms.

I found out how login with login and password in Hippo cms using web page. (using /login/proxy with POST) but how can I register new users?

Of course I do not want users to have to go into the console. I just need a simple registration page where the user enters the name of the email and password. Is it possible affordable way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no registration form. You will have to create it yourself by creating an [html form with the HST](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hst-2-forms.html) and writing it to the user registry, which is stored in the repository under `/hippo:configuration/hippo:users` You can do this from within the **doAction** method of your component.

Comment: I connected component with the page on which I have the 'username ' mail ' ' password ' and I did doAction method :
    FormMap map = new FormMap(request, new String[]{"username","mail","password"});
But how can I get to repository and add new user in /hippo:configuration/hippo:users ?

Comment: You might want to read http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-persistable-annotation-and-workflow.html and check out Example 2, which explains how to get a writable session with the @Persistable annotation. From there on you can just get the users node and write to it.

Comment: Do I need set all 'settlers" in User bean? How can I overwrite this class?

It is a good way to get users node?
Node users = persistableSession.getNode(/hippo:configuration/hippo:users);

Comment: Yes that's a good way to get the node. You don't need a Bean, you can also just work with the session. However this starts become more like a Q and A session, so I don't think that's suitable here. I would create a new question or post on the hippo community forum groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hippo-community if you need to know more.